# IntelliJ migrate to Junit5 - empty refactor window

Tags: intellij-idea, migration, junit5

I am trying to migrate code from Junit4 to Junit5, I've found a tutorial [here on jetbrains site](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tutorials/migrating-junit4-junit5/). I enabled the inspections as showed in tutorial, and have an option to "Migrate to Junit5". However when I trigger it I am presented with empty refactor window:

[image: empty_refactor_window_migrate_to_junit5]

Is there something I didn't catch? I can see that I still have active `import org.junit.Test;` statements so from what I understand these would be changed by auto migration.

I am using newest IntelliJ Ultimate 2021.1.2

Comment: Looks like IDEA can not find your tests. But I don't have any idea why.

Comment: Please share the code sample. You may also create an issue at YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA and attach the sample project to it.

Comment: Hmm weird thing - today I had update and it started working.